# How to deal with mutually depending clients?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, direct-line-botframework

Based on [this argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438105/using-azure-bot-service-with-non-channel-configurable-chat-service), I'm implementing classes which will handle messaging between Discord and DirectLine API.

Then, however, I'm not sure how to achieve the best practice to implement the two clients, which will mutually depend on the others. I've ever heard that it is indicating the design is something wrong when I have a mutual dependency.

Currently, I have some code (not entire function) shown below. Is there any suggestion about this trial?

**Startup.cs**
Add singletons for DI.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSingleton<IDirectLineClient, DirectLineClient>();
        services.AddSingleton<IDiscordClient, DiscordClient>();
        ...
    }
```

**DiscordClient.cs**
Handle messages from users on Discord and pass them to DirectLine API.

```
namespace Microsoft.Chive
{
    public interface IDiscordClient
    {
        Task RespondMessage(SocketMessage socketMessage);
    }
    public class DiscordClient : IDiscordClient
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private IServiceProvider _provider;
        private CommandService _commands;
        private static string _secret;
        private static IDirectLineClient _directLineClient;

        public DiscordClient(IDirectLineClient directLineClient, IConfiguration Configuration, IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            _provider = provider;
            _directLineClient = directLineClient;
            _secret = Configuration.GetSection("discordClientSecret")?.Value;
        }

        public static Task<DiscordClient> InitializeAsync(IDirectLineClient directLineClient, IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            var instance = new DiscordClient(directLineClient, configuration, provider);
            return instance.InitializeInstance();
        }

        private async Task<DiscordClient> InitializeInstance()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _client.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceive;
            _commands = new CommandService();

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, _secret);
            await _client.StartAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1);
            return this;
        }


        private async Task OnMessageReceive(SocketMessage socketMessage)
        {
            var message = socketMessage as SocketUserMessage;
            await _directLineClient.PostMessageAsync(message.Content);
        }


        public async Task RespondMessage(SocketMessage socketMessage)
        {
            var message = socketMessage as SocketUserMessage;
            var context = new CommandContext(_client, message);

            await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, 0, _provider);
        }
    }
}
```

**DirectLineClient.cs**
Relay the response from DirectLine API to Discord Client.

```
public interface IDirectLineClient
{
    Task PostMessageAsync(string message);
}

public class DirectLineClient : IDirectLineClient
{
    private static string _secret;
    private static string _handle;
    private Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine.DirectLineClient _client;
    private Conversation _conversation;
    private IDiscordClient _discordClient;

    public DirectLineClient(IDiscordClient discordClient, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this._discordClient = discordClient;
        _handle = configuration.GetSection("directLineHandle")?.Value;
        _secret = configuration.GetSection("directLineSecret")?.Value;
    }

    public static Task<DirectLineClient> InitializeAsync(IDiscordClient discordClient, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var instance = new DirectLineClient(discordClient, configuration);
        return instance.InitializeInstance();
    }

    private async Task<DirectLineClient> InitializeInstance()
    {
        _client = new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine.DirectLineClient(_secret);
        return this;
    }

    public async Task StartConversation()
    {
        _conversation = await _client.Conversations.StartConversationAsync();
    }

    public async Task PostMessageAsync(string message)
    {
        var activity = new Activity
        {
            From = new ChannelAccount("user"),
            Text = message,
            Type = ActivityTypes.Message
        };
        await _client.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(_conversation.ConversationId, activity);
    }

    public async Task OnResponseReceive(SocketMessage socketMessage)
    {
        await _discordClient.RespondMessage(socketMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are patterns to achieve decoupling in situations like this: mediator, event aggregator.

Comment: Even if I use a mediator, a dependency between the clients will still indirectly there and look like ClientA<->Mediator<->ClientB instead of ClientA<->ClientB. Why the former is yes and the latter is no?

Comment: There is no yes or no but rather pros and cons and you decide what's better for you. Dealing with direct mutual dependencies in an IoC is tricky so mediator can at least solve it by providing additional interface for a "handshake". If you aren't going to have complex orchestration logic the event aggregator is better choice as you don't need to know the contracts details - only consume the notifications.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the reply. That makes sense and I will go mediator option for what I'm working on. Thank you.